# standalone break within a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

I stumbled upon this code, which works as expected:

```
switch (ev->deviceType) {

    break;

    case DEVICE_TS1E0:
        //some code
        break;

    case DEVICE_TS1E3:
       //some code
       break;

    default:
        //some logging
        break;
}
```

Now, there's a lonesome `break;` at the start of the switch, which appears to have no effect.

Is there any circumstances where that `break;` would have an effect ?

Comment: That looks like the remaining of a poor code cleanup to me...

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this doesn't do anything unexpected. Even if the `switch` is in a loop, the stray `break` is a NOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** That `break` statement is ineffective and a dead-code. Control will never reach there.

`C11` standard has a pretty good example of a similar case, let me quote that straight.

From Chapter §6.8.4.2/7, (*emphasis mine*)

> EXAMPLE In the artificial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>     int i = 4;
>     f(i);
> case 0:
>     i = 17;
>     /* falls through into default code */
> default:
>     printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the block) but **is never
>   initialized,** and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the `printf` function will
>   access an indeterminate value. Similarly, the **call to the function `f` cannot be reached.**

Comment: I actually wonder why the standard allows anything else than variable declarations before the first case.

Comment: @MichaelWalz That's the same situation as in `if (foo) { return; } else { return; } return;`, there is dead code, but it must be valid code.

Comment: @fluter sure, but the standard could forbid such constructs because _any_ statements other than declarations before the first `case` will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

That statement, along any other statements that is not in a `case` clause in `switch` statement are unreachable code, aka dead code. That means they will not be run anyway. It is not recommended to use them.